# filtered sub-queue from big queue or several subqueue with organization to one big - how to implement?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Here's what i want to do:

1. One general queue with all elements 

2. Several sub-queues with elements filtered by certain criteria, their sets of elements won't be crossing each other. 

3. If element deleted from general queue it will be deleted from corresponding sub-queue.

By deletion i mean it won't be returned by iterator, not necessarily deleted right away.

Right now i'm thinking of holding several vectors with sub-vectors. Altrough it will be pain to access random element from it, because criteria which i will use to sort objects to corresponding queue won't be anyhow related to criteria by which i will be seeking object in general queue.

If be more specific i want a event queue with several subqueue filtered by certain criteria, for example origin point of event.

Comment: Actually nothing at all, still thinking how to implement it.

Comment: Reading this description I can only think of Boost Intrusive Containers

Comment: Well, if you're using a queue you should be taking the first element from the queue (not a random element), so your question can be answered by asking yourself: do I need the first element overall, or do I need the first element that confirms to certain criteria?
(...or do I need something else than a queue?)